# The metric identification of $(S,d)$ with different equivalence relation.

Tags: general-topology

Let $(S,d)$ be a pseudometric space. Define an equivalence relation ∼ on S by $x ∼ y$ iff $\overline{\{x\}}=\overline{\{y\}}$. If $S^*$ is the set of equivalence classes in $S$ under the equivalence relation ∼ and if $d^*$ is defined by $d^*([x],[y])=d(x,y)$ is a well-defined metric on $S^*$. The metric space $(S^*,d^*)$ is called the metric identification of $(S,d)$.

My attempt:
See that ∼ is an equvalence relation is easy, what I did is prove that that $S^*$ is $T_0$ space by $x \neq y$ then $\overline{\{x\}}\neq\overline{\{y\}}$
What I see is that in this [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443564/metric-space-elementary-analysis) is very similar but the ∼ is different, so could you guide me to solve this?

Comment: If you show that $\operatorname{cl}\{x\}=\{y\in M:d(x,y)=0$, you’ll have reduced your problem to the one to which you linked.

Comment: I have problems to prove $\{y\in M:d(x,y)=0\} \subset \operatorname{cl}\{x\} $, could you give me a hint?

Comment: The open balls are a base for the pseudometric topology, so $y\notin\operatorname{cl}\{x\}$ iff there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(y,\epsilon)\cap\{x\}=\varnothing$.